# ReportViewer : Method not found (IE)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, reportviewer

I have integrated ReportViewerto bind reports in aspx page. It's working fine and I am able to see the reports on all browsers(including IE) in local(developer) machine. Now, I have deployed my solution to live (azure cloud) server. I am getting this error

```
Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.ReportingServices.Common.DateTimeUtil.TryParseDateTime(System.String, System.IFormatProvider, System.DateTimeOffset ByRef, Boolean ByRef)
```

on IE. Strange thing is I am able to see the live server's reports on all other browser(chrome, mozilla). Could anybody help me to get rid of this. Many thanks in advance.